# Deletion behavior of rm *

Tags: rm

If I execute `rm *` within a directory containing files, are only files in this directory deleted? Or does the asterisk include the filesystem root `/` as well?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this if you don't know what it does. I would suggest you check the documentation for `rm`, and if there's anything you don't understand, come back and ask about that specifically.

Comment: See the documentation, specifically the `-i` switch. Then run `rm -i *` in a test directory and answer `n` for every prompt, so it's harmless. Observe the behavior.

Comment: If you do `rm *`,  `rm` does not see the `*` in fact, as this gets expanded by the shell even before starting `rm` (except if nothing matches probably). So how the shell expands it depends on the shell. But typically it is everything in current directory, except files starting with `.`, but including directories (just their name, not their content or subdirectories).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You are assuming that this happened deliberately :) :| :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as plain filenames refer to items in the current directory, `*` also expands to items in the current directory. There's no mechanism that would make it include `/` among the results. (You can always test using `echo *`.)

So all files in the current directory will be removed, but directories will remain because you didn't specify the option to remove directories recursively (-r).

If you enable recursive mode using `rm -r`, *then* files and subdirectories will be removed – but the program will only go downwards, never upwards. (rm always skips the `..` item that refers to "parent directories". In fact, on Linux, even if you try to deliberately `rm -r ..` it will show a warning and refuse to do that.)

Answer (score 2):

To confirm what `*` is expanded to by the current shell, run:

```
echo *
```

By default it includes only non-hidden files/directories in the current folders. For hidden files, set `dotglob`.

---

However, if you run:

```
echo .*
```

By default it is going to include all hidden files, along with the current folder (`.`) and the parent one (`..`).

<sup>For workaround, see: [How to use the .* wildcard in bash but exclude the parent directory (..)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2910049/55075)</sup>